# "Whether, not whether"

Tags: meaning

I'm not a native speaker, I think this is why I'm a bit confused about the usage of *whether* in the sentence below:

> *Whether*
>   a reference refers to a const or nonconst type affects what we can do with that reference,
>   *not whether* we can alter the binding of the reference itself.

What does *whether...*, *not whether* mean in this sentence?

Comment: Rough paraphrase without "whether" A reference will refer to a const type or a non-const type, and that affects what can be done with the reference, but does not affect if the binding of the reference can be altered.

Comment: This type of question would be more suitably addressed on the English Language Learners site.

Comment: A reference's type, such as const or nonconst, affects what we can do with that reference, not whether we can alter the binding of the reference itself.

Comment: It's a bad example because it is a very confusingly worded sentence. Especially the way they used *whether* and *not whether.* The first *whether* is creating a bit of a garden path situation here.

Comment: [Whether A or B is the case] affects [C], not [whether or not we can do D].

Comment: _Not whether_ is not a constituent. The _not_ is not connected to _whether_, but to the whole clause that _whether_ introduces.

Comment: What we can do is affected by whether the reference refers to const or nonconst type, and not by the binding of the reference that can be altered by us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments explained it pretty well, but to just lay it out in one place:

**Whether** is used to introduce alternatives, separated by "or".

> It does not matter **whether** you have high **or** low grades in this university.

Sometimes the second alternative is not mentioned, just implied. You can infer the second alternative to mean the opposite of the first one.

> It does not matter **whether** you have high grades in this university.

In your example sentence, there are two whether-clauses. One of them gives two alternatives (a reference refers to a const type, or to a nonconst type). The second has the second alternative implied. Adding an explicit "or not" can help to unravel it better:

> **Whether** a reference refers to a const **or** nonconst type affects what we can do with that reference, not **whether** we can alter the binding of the reference itself **or not**.

Without using any whether, it could be reworded to:

> A reference can refer to a const or to a nonconst type. That affects what we can do with that reference, not the possibility of altering the binding of the reference itself.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence has the form:
Whether A affects B not C.

It means: Whether A affects B; but whether A does not affect C.

Now the confusing thing is that C begins with the word "whether", even though that "whether" is unrelated to the earlier "whether".